# sendkeys selenium vba from copied selection in excel

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, automation

I am trying to copy a range of cells to the clipboard and paste it.

```
Global bot As New ChromeDriver, post As Object
Public MyElement As selenium.WebElement
Public Keys As selenium.Keys

Sub copyPasteintoGoogleSearchBar()
  
 Set Keys = CreateObject("Selenium.Keys")
  
    loginAndGoToTesting
    
    With bot
        Range("A2:L2").Copy
        .FindElementByName("q").SendKeys (Keys.Control  + "v")   
    End With
End Sub

Function loginAndGoToTesting()

With bot
    .Timeouts.ImplicitWait = 1000
   ' .AddArgument "--headless"
    .Start
    .get "https://www.google.com/"
    bot.Window.SetSize 2000, 1200
    bot.Window.Maximize
    bot.Refresh
End With
End Function
```

It will act like it is doing something and then nothing. If you manually right click on the url(not seeing a way to clickContext with selenium on the Url) before sending keys of ctrl and v it will paste in. rick click(click context) on the google search bar does not change the result of it not pastin

Comment: why do you copy it when you can just send the range? `.FindElementByName("q").SendKeys Range("A2:L2").Value`, if it doesn't work like this, you may try to build a string by looping through the cells an add a breakline (Chr(10)) in between.
PS: Don't spam questions with [different headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73651341/how-to-copy-a-cell-range-of-cells-and-paste-on-that-webpage-selenium-vba)

Comment: sending keys does not work like that. Why I am trying to copying and paste: it is a piece to a larger one. I am going to copy about 38,000 rows with 10 columns into a web application. Within that application you can manually do this by control v into that web element  and then it will auto-populate.  Looping through the columns or rows each cell value would have to be inputted one at a time into each web element and would take some hours.